# ProcessStartInfo.Verb multiple verbs

Tags: .net, process

I cant seem to find the syntax on how to create more than one verb properly

do I create a String() and set it? is it comma delimited, can I just set the property twice?

I dont know, cant find.

I need to 'runas' and 'print'

Comment: That is not possible.  Consider writing a tiny app that asks for elevation with its manifest and does nothing but invoke the print verb.

Answer (score 0):

I read elsewhere that to run elevated i need to add the .verb 'runas' however it turns out 'runas' is not a verb for ProcessStartInfo so I guess that answer was wrong.